# Copy legend from ArcMap A to ArcMap B with different scales and/or paper size?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, legend, copy, paper, paste

I have a question for you  and what is the best practice for me to copy the legend from another ArcMap A to ArcMap B. They are in the Layout View. it has different scale like in 1: 77,000 to 1:55,000 without having to adjust the legend ?

So here is the example of what I am talking about here:

ArcMap  A Layout View ..............................                                                        ArcMap B  Layout View

Scale : 1: 77,000                ----------------->      Scale : 1:55, 000

[image]

So the legend from the 77,000 seem to be bigger than the 55,000 and when I resize it to meet the same as the 55,000 it seems that the symbol gets smaller and the symbol changes. I had to fix it and try to resize but the symbols were not desired what I wanted.

What is the method or a way around to fix this ?

Comment: If you want to change scale the legen symbol automatically according to the scale, you have to set a data frame. In the data frame properties, you have to set (reference scale, e.g 77,000). And from the legend properties, toggle on ( scale symbol when reference scale is set). Then, when you copy your legend to ArcMap B, set the reference scale of the data frame to the desired scale (e.g 55,000) and the legend symbol will change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but I just found out when you have a paper size is different like from ArcMap A (36x36) to ArcMap (36x44) the legend is smaller and when you resize it it becomes smaller and hard to read.